# ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.3.1

Tags: python, installation, kivy, python-3.10

**Hello I am trying to install kivy with python 3.10** (most latest as of this ques) it is giving me an error
 `ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.3.1`

then it is also trying to install Kivy-1.11.1.tar.gz and I am getting more errors out

[Screenshot{errors(kivy)}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lazGI.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because at this time Kivy only supports Python 3.6-3.9.

Here is what I see on Kivy page

[image]

So, you can install virtual environment of Python 3.9 and try again. It worked for me.